# wp_query - show all authors at selected category who wrote Posts for this category

Tags: php, wordpress

I need your help, I am an newbie on `wp_query` 
and I don't know how I'll can show all authors at selected category who wrote Posts for this category.
so this means I go on my page for example to: Hobbies
then I want to show all posts with this category and those authors who wrote this Posts.

I searched so much and found something like this but its not that what I need >_>
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/134347/how-to-query-posts-from-specific-authors-and-categories-using-wp-query

Hope it is clear what I mean?

Hope you can help me out :)

EDIT:

ah okay thank you! i tried the code on my code but nothing happend on my site :,D

what do i wrong? :/

```
<?php
    $get_cat_id = get_the_category();

    $args = array(
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array ( $get_cat_id),
            )
        )
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

    //the loop
    $firstEntry = true;
    if ( $the_query -> have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query -> have_posts() ) {
            echo $firstEntry ? '<article class="active">' : '<article>';
            $firstEntry = false;
            $the_query -> the_post();
            $last = get_the_author_meta('last_name');
            $first = get_the_author_meta('first_name');
            echo '<h3 class="author"><a href="'. get_the_author_meta('display_name') . '">' .  $first . " " . $last . '</a></h3>';
            echo '<img src="<?php echo $template_uri; ?>/img/author_mini.jpg" alt="THOMAS SCHRÖDER" class="thumb-round">';
            echo '</article>';
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }

?>
```

EDIT2:

Ok sry for my bad english and that you dont really understand what i mean :/
i dont know how i can better explane my problem :(

i debug the arr $the_query and this is some output from it

```
object(WP_Query)[2458]
public 'query' =>
array (size=1)
'tax_query' =>
array (size=1)
0 =>
array (size=3)
...
public 'query_vars' =>
array (size=62)
'tax_query' =>
array (size=1)
0 =>
array (size=3)
...
'error' => string '' (length=0)
'm' => string '' (length=0)
'p' => int 0
'post_parent' => string '' (length=0)
'subpost' => string '' (length=0)
'subpost_id' => string '' (length=0)
'attachment' => string '' (length=0)
'attachment_id' => int 0
'name' => string '' (length=0)
'static' => string '' (length=0)
'pagename' => string '' (length=0)
'page_id' => int 0
'second' => string '' (length=0)
'minute' => string '' (length=0)
'hour' => string '' (length=0)
'day' => int 0
'monthnum' => int 0
'year' => int 0
'w' => int 0
'category_name' => string 'allgemein' (length=9)
'tag' => string '' (length=0)
'cat' => int 1
'tag_id' => string '' (length=0)
'author' => string '' (length=0)
'author_name' => string '' (length=0)
'feed' => string '' (length=0)
'tb' => string '' (length=0)
'paged' => int 0
'comments_popup' => string '' (length=0)
'meta_key' => string '' (length=0)
'meta_value' => string '' (length=0)
'preview' => string '' (length=0)
's' => string '' (length=0)
'sentence' => string '' (length=0)
'fields' => string '' (length=0)
'menu_order' => string '' (length=0)
'category__in' =>
array (size=0)
```

Comment: you need to format your code in SO. google how to do that if you are not sure.

Comment: do some debugging - you know some `PHP` right? try this stuff first -> http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php

Comment: there is a lot of code in there. maybe start with less. just display the author names then add the rest afterwards. not sure `$the_query -> the_post();` is going to help you in the while loop. also look at the WordPress Codex

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to do a custom `WP query`.

break it down:

1. you need to know what post you are on (and what category it has)
2. then query the category for all posts
3. and from these posts get the author.

so

```
$get_cat_id = get_the_category();

$query = new wp_query($arr);
$arr = array(
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'id',
    'terms' => array ( $get_cat_id),
    )
)
);
```

then `foreach` `post` within the `category`

```
get_the_author_id();
```

or something similar.

Comment: so i check the arrays and so on but i dont know why it's not working.. there is somewhere a problem with "if ( $the_query -> have_posts() )"
because he goes does not even purely in this If statment.. but why?.. :/

Comment: So you checked with var-dump , did you get data or not? , I can't understand what you are saying. Add to your question some of the output. You need to read the codex and understand the has posts query.

Comment: yes i do, i post this on top EDIT2, sry for my bad english :/